# How to check webservice response in database using Selenium or UFT

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, database, uft-12.52

I have an application. Different web services gets called when any action is performed. Let me explain my scenario:

When I update a value in application, it also gets updated in LPS system. The LPS is updated by using web-services. If we received success in `web-service_receive` then it means value is successfully updated in LPS.

I want to check whether I get success or not whenever a web-service gets called.

[image: This is the screenshot of database table]

In database, a new record gets inserted every time a web-service is called. One with `webservice_receive` and one with `webservice_sent`.

Is there any way to automate this scenario. Screenshot of database table is attached.

Comment: Can you clarify your question in aspect of Selenium/UFT. Do you mean you are okay with the solution either for Selenium or for UFT? Or you expect to combine those two frameworks somehow?

Comment: I am okay with any of the solution. Either for Selenium or UFT.

Comment: Is the application you're talking about a web-application or a desktop application? Also what does LPS stand for?

Comment: It's a web application. LPS (Mainframe application)  is comprehensive system used by financial institutions to manage all servicing processes, including loan boarding, payment processing and escrow administration, giving servicers a fully integrated system to meet mortgage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way I would suggest you implement this:

- Use a proxy like Browsermob(https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) when initiating your selenium tests and capture HAR content
- Once the test is complete(OR while the test is still in progress), you may parse the HAR file to check if the web-service was called and a valid response was returned by the server
- If a successful response was served, query the database and validate the database entry

An example for using Browsermob with selenium can be found in the readme section here: https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium